# Click-->FadeIn-->setTimout-->FadeOut

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I am js beginner and struggling with a beginner issue.

What I want to have is the following: fadeIn a li-Element on.click and after, say 5 seconds, fadeOut again. If s.o. clicks more than once on the element within the 5 seconds, start to count the 5 seconds for fadeOut from new.

I have the basics together and in theory it looks like this:

```
$("#boxes li").on("click",function() {
    $(this).find(".front,.back").fadeToggle(800).delay(5000).fadeToggle(800);
});
```

However, I would need `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` in order to start counting the delay from new when clicking the li-Element again within the 5 seconds for fading out properly.

Though knowing the theory around it I do not seem to get handle on the code behind it.

Thanks for any suggestions and please keep in mind that I am a beginner when you try to explain smth.

**EDIT**

according to Pete's idea I've created a fiddle that is more like that I want to achieve. For some reason it does not quite work with fadeToggle. Here is the updated example as fiddle:

**http://jsfiddle.net/sfiddle/jLurZ/**

You will notice, the clicked div wont toggle back, let alone the functionality that I want to achieve with the if statement.

Best regards,

Comment: You can get more than just theory by reading up the jquery API (http://api.jquery.com/) and seeing their examples on using delay.  You can also Google for settimeout() examples on the web and apply the two together.

Comment: Thank you blachawk, I know that site and the documentation and believe me I googled a lot before coming here. The problem is that I am so much of a beginner that I would need some help (even with basic things) to get me started. Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
$("#boxes li").on("click",function({    
    $('.front,.back').stop().hide().fadeToggle(800, function() {
        $(this).delay(1500).fadeToggle(800);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gZ3TS/1/

**EDIT**

jQuery work-around to reset if clicked second time: http://jsfiddle.net/gZ3TS/6/

using `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`: http://jsfiddle.net/gZ3TS/11/

**UPDATE**

multiple fading boxes - unfortunately I can't use the `fadeToggle` due to the nature of having to keep the box in a certain state if the user clicks during the middle of an animation sequence

http://jsfiddle.net/gZ3TS/31/

Comment: Hi Pete, that won't work. If I click a second time on the element it would reset the counter but instead of fading it out after 5 seconds it starts with fading it out and then after five seconds fading it in. The result should be that if clicked it fades in and when I click once more within the delay it stays faded in only reseting the countdown for the delay. In the end it should fade out.

Comment: It's a bit of a workaround but does what you want it to: http://jsfiddle.net/gZ3TS/6/

Comment: Thanks Pete that workaround worked. I still don't get it why my approach and actually @Billy Mathews approach wouldn't work. It seemed the most logical think for me ... Yours works but I have to get my head around it how actually .... thanks anyway

Comment: I think the problem comes with having to do a check to see if you are half way through the animation sequence on subsequent clicks, instead of the toggle you need to state that if you are halfway through an animation that you start from the object visible and then fade out.  With fade toggle it just starts of from where you left off and goes the opposite way

Comment: Hmm ... interesting. But the concept was straight forward. fadeIn and after a setTimeout fadeOut. If anybody calls again the function within settimeout-phase reset it, execute the fadeOut and good night. JS is very strange ... sometimes I feel it's the most logic thing ever but most often as a beginner you'll find that logic input is a complete stranger to js. PS: note that I dont blame js - I know that the odd thinking is from my part.

Comment: ah now that you have explained it like that here is a version using your timeout:  http://jsfiddle.net/gZ3TS/11/.  I also hate javascript which is why I always try to use jquery as it seems more logical and simpler to use than pure js

Comment: Hi Pete, that's what I was looking for. Didn't check it in my ul, but your fiddle shows exactly what I am after...thx

Comment: Hi Pete, please have a look at my edit. The last hour I spent with understanding your code which worked in your fiddle but it wouldn't with the concept of fadeToggle. I'll certainly give you the credit you deserve and it's very close to that I want to achieve but not quite. However I'll rank you for now further up and certainly accept your answer - just wanted to point out that my issues are not quite resolved

Comment: Okay have now done a solution using your html see edit above (I currently have nothing to do at work!)

Comment: Hi Pete, this seems to work. Again I will go through the code as my main priority is to understand what others code to being able to do that myself one day. It's fascinating how the code got more and more complex :-) and I was very surprised that fadeToggle wouldn't be a propper state to build uppon.

Comment: Hi Pete, I can confirm now that your code works great. I went through it, adapted naming to fit my html/css and its fantastic. As it is my major wish to understand everything I do in js I wanted to ask you whether you could commet on one of your lines:
timeoutVar[arrayIndex] = setTimeout(function() { fadeOut(li, front, back); }, delayTime);
obviously timeoutVar will allow us to call upont setTimeout with clearTimeout, correct? But what I don't understand is the notation after fadeOut: what effect does it have that you insert some DOM elements in the paranthese? I tried it wouldn't work without

Comment: I tried to make the elements within the function but it wouldn't work for some reason - one of javascript's little quirks I guess.  I passed them through to the function so that it would be the correct objects being used.  As you have multiple elements that can be fading at any one time it just makes sure that it is the clicked elements that are the ones that are being affected

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var fadeoutnow;
$("#boxes li").on("click",function({

    $(this).find(".front, .back").fadeToggle(800);

    clearTimeout(fadeoutnow);

    //You can assign the timeout function to a variable so that you can clear it (above)
    fadeoutnow = setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).find(".front, .back").fadeToggle(800);
    }, 5000);

});
```

Comment: Hi Billy Mathews, I tried to copy your code but it wouldn't function. The li-Element in question does nothing. If I try to interprete your code it would be onClick do the following function on the clicked li-element, checking its class whether front or back and switch that class accordingly within 0.8 seconds. In execute this function after 5 seconds: fadeToggle the li-element from before switching back the classes within 0.8 seconds. And if I click again on the li-element within the 5 seconds delay reset the counter but execute the final fadeToggle, correct?

Comment: Still no luck. nothing happens. It seems that a semicolon or so is missing as it also breaks js below that worked great so far. Other suggestions?

Comment: @user2132380 I'm not sure why.. maybe you should declare the variable before hand - try now?

Comment: @user2132380 and there was a semicolon missing.. sorry :p

Comment: Hi Billy Mathews, still no luck - still you try would break subsequent js. Note that I only exchange my lines of code as stated above with yours which would lead to non-functioning. That's strange and even thoug an easy concept I spent quite some hours on this already